# Cost of console.log for Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there an extra cost for calling multiple console.log() in a firebase Cloud Function?

While I find it most useful to see certain details in my cloud function logs online, I was wondering if storage costs for these logs or processing costs are generated for having multiple console.log() in the SAME cloud function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no extra cost for those logs, but they are [subject to Stack Driver quota policy](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas). This means for example that only the last 30 days of logs are retained, but check the documentation for full details.

Comment: I just discovered that I am being charged for using the Firebase console. I filtered and bam, an extra 7000 reads.

Comment: You'e charged for all documents that are read on the server on your behalf. Since displaying documents in the console requires that they're read from the server, you'll be charged for those. The console should be quite conservative in how much data it reads though. If that doesn't seem to be the case for you, Id [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: This is outdated information.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is a cost for logging into the cloud...

Yes, you get a free quota to start with, but any extra usage means you will pay.

You can review the **logging cost** in the stackdriver documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing

Comment: `Logging != console.log()` and your answer is wrong. Frank already answered this question 4 years before.

Comment: @Mises ... please read the comments on Frank's answers... and also Frank's answer itself, which mentioned the quota.

Comment: This is the right answer.